# Discord-JDA: Как получить данные об Юзере, добавившегося на сервер?

Tags: java, discord-api, discord-jda

Как мне присвоить юзера, зашедшего впервые на сервер, к переменной `User newUser`?

Часть программ.
`Main.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try {
        JDA api = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(token).build();
        api.addEventListener(new MyEventListener(api));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`MyEventListener.java`:

```
     public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
       User newUser;

    }
```

Я читаю Javadoc и возможно мне надо использовать [GuildMemberJoinEvent()](http://home.dv8tion.net:8080/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/events/guild/member/GuildMemberJoinEvent.html). Если это то, что мне нужно, то помогите, пожалуйста, примером кода как использовать правильно эту функцию для моей программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пободавшись с программистами по улучшении JDA библиотеки, я понял как это делается.

Нужно использовать `onGuildMemberJoin`.

Добавляем в ваш "Listner" фунцию `onGuildMemberJoin`.

```
//Get user that joined the server
@Override
public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
    System.out.println("NEW USER!!!!! YEAH! - " + event.getUser().getName());
}
```

В **Eclipse** это можно сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **IntelliJ**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]